# How to regex match words? (in multiple languages)

Tags: regular-expressions, unicode

I have a simple regex search which matches `[A-Za-z]`, however I would like it to match other characters which would be used in dictionary words for non-english languages. e.g. `ü`, `Ø`, `ɵ` `人参`, while excluding:

- White space.
- Punctuation.
- Numbers.
- Other non-language symbols arrows, characters for drawing diagrams ... etc.

How can Emacs regex match against unicode words used in language?

I tried `[:word:]` but this matches numbers.

Comment: Thanks, thats it (can be made into answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the character class `[:alpha:]`

E.g. `[[:alpha:]]+` to match one-or-more such characters.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Char Classes` says:

> ```
> [:alpha:]
> ```
>
> This matches any letter.  For multibyte characters, it matches characters whose Unicode `general-category` property (*note Character Properties::) indicates they are alphabetic characters.

Whereas you were using:

> ```
> [:word:]
> ```
>
> This matches any character that has word syntax (*note Syntax Class Table::).